# XML sql query , attribute as column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I need to query xml data available in server

```
<root>
  <Parameter>
     <Param>APP_REG_NUMBER</Param>
     <Value>AL/T/2010/86</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
      <Param>SUBLINEID</Param>
      <Value>235931</Value>
  </Parameter>
</root>
```

This is the structure I am saving data into SQL Server, I need output as follows:

```
Filed1     , Filed2   , APP_REG_NUMBER,  SUBLINEID
something   something , AL/T/2010/86, 235931
```

please do the needful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XQuery for this, but realize you are recreating key-value-pairs in XML, which negates the ability to use schemas or XQuery/XPATH in any reasonable manner.  Consider changing the format to:

```
<root>
    <APP_REG_NUMBER>AL/T/2010/86</APP_REG_NUMBER>
    <SUBLINEID>235931</SUBLINEID>
</root>
```

I digress... the query you want is:

```
DECLARE @testXml xml = N'<root>
  <Parameter><Param>APP_REG_NUMBER</Param><Value>AL/T/2010/86</Value></Parameter>
  <Parameter><Param>SUBLINEID</Param><Value>235931</Value></Parameter>
</root>'

SELECT 
    @testXml.value('(//Parameter[Param/text()="APP_REG_NUMBER"]/Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as APP_REG_NUMBER,
    @testXml.value('(//Parameter[Param/text()="SUBLINEID"]/Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as SUBLINEID
```

You use the `//Parameter` syntax to find all `Parameter` elements and then filter them (`[Param/text()="foobar"]`) to only those which have a child named `Value` that have the inner text of `SUBLINEID`.  From there, you navigate to the `/Value` child element and return the first result (`(query)[1]`).